# JS - error: Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined

Tags: javascript, api, p5.js, codepen

im creating an application using the P5.JS library that shows a dinamic map with each country colored by its current weather, this is what i have so far:

```cs
var colors = [];
var paises = ["AR", "BR", "CL", "CO", "GY", "PE", "PY", "UY", "BO", "VE", "EC", "GF", "SR"];

var datacoor;

var url1 = "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?";
var arg1 = "cht=map&chs=600x500&chld="
var arg2 = "&chco=";
//var URL = url1+arguments;

var img;

function setup () {
  createCanvas(500, 600);
  img = createImg("https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=map&chs=600x500&chld=AR|BR|CL|CO|GY|PE|PY|UY|BO|VE|EC|GF|SR&chco=B3BCC0|5781AE");
  img.hide();

  for (var a = 0; a < paises.length; a++){
    colors.append(colors, color(getColor(paises[a])));

  }
}

function draw  () {
  background(255);

  noStroke();
  fill(30);
  textSize(35);
  //text("zz ", 15, 45);

  if (img) {
    imageMode(CENTER);
    image(img, width/2, height/2);
  }
}

function onData (response) {
  datacoor = response;
  console.log(datacoor);
}

function getColor (loc) {
  var pais = loc;
  var lat;
  var long;

  if (data1.hasOwnProperty(pais)) {
        lat = data1.pais.lat;
        console.log(lat);
    }

}
```

here´s the problem:

```cs
function getColor (loc) {
  var pais = loc;
  var lat;
  var long;

//data1 is a variable with the list of all countries and their coordinates
  if (data1.hasOwnProperty(pais)) {
        lat = data1.pais.lat;
        console.log(lat);
    }

}
```

its looking for the object "pais" instead of the object inside of the variable "pais", how can i fix this? Any help appreciated

Comment: That means that `data1.pais` doesn't exist. Debug to find out why.

Comment: i know what it means and what the problem is, i just dont know how to fix it

Comment: `data1` is an object to you created right? Go to where `pais` is assigned, and make sure it's actually being assigned all the time. Posting that code here would help too.

Comment: i need to get the object thats stored in the variable "pais" from "data1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to guess you meant to do:

```
lat = data1[pais].lat;
```

`pais` will be interpreted as a string, and should act as you intend by getting the property with the value of the variable `pais`.

This is known as ["bracket notation".](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)

Comment: @user87073 Remember, Javascript objects are just Maps/Dictionaries/Associative Arrays (whatever you want to call them), and are very similar to arrays. You would do `arr[0]` to get the first element of an array, but `dict["someProp"]` to get the `"someProp"` property of the dictionary. Read the link I posted in the answer to get a better understanding.